# Finding A Series For the Function Question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Would anyone possibly be able to show me how the following solution was arrived at?

I have the function:
$f(x) = e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$
and I need to find the series for the function.

The back of the book says the answer is the $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{\color{red}{2n}}}{\color{red}{2^n}n!}$.

I would have guessed you would have to use $\frac{n^2}{2}$ in both spots I coloured red.  I know you can use the series $e^x$ to figure this out, but I am really not sure how they did that.  If anyone has a moment to explain it I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange.  Please make an effort to LaTeXify your question, so that people understand it.

Comment: My apologies on the formatting -- thank you providing for the fix.

Answer (score 5):

$$\forall\,x\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\implies e^{x^2/2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac{x^2}2\right)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n}}{2^nn!}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!  This was much simpler than I had been making it out to be...

Comment: @user2604445 , my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

The series for $e^x$ is
$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$
Just plug in $\frac{x^2}{2}$ for $x$. We get
$$e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{2^n n!}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the Taylor series for $f(x)=e^x$ is given by $$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
Now, in the example you have, your exponent is raised to the power of $\frac{x^2}{2}$, thus simply substituting into the above gives
$$e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\frac{x^2}{2})^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n}}{2^nn!}$$